# find MAX,MIN and AVG of a set in Django

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

I have an object called *meter* and it has a set called *powerConsumptionReport_set*.

This is the models.py :

```
class Meter(models.Model):
region                  = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=1)
IPAddress               = models.GenericIPAddressField(default=0,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
PortNumber              = models.IntegerField(default=1024)
SerialNumber            = models.IntegerField(default=00000000,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)

class PowerConsumptionReport(models.Model):
meter = models.ForeignKey(Meter, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
power = models.FloatField()
```

I need to find Max value of *power* field from the *powerConsumptionReport_set* and display it in my template.

This is the DetailView i used to show each Meter :

```
class MeterDetailView(DetailView):
model = Meter
template_name = 'meter/specificMeter.html'
```

And the template is here:

```
<h1>
*** here i want to show min value of the set **** - 
{{ meter.powerconsumptionreport_set.first.power }} 
</h1>
```

how can i access Max,Min and AVG value of **power** field from the powerConsumptionReport_set related to each meter.

Cheers.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe getting these values in views.py is better than doing it in a template.
You can achieve this:

```
PowerConsumptionReport.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('power '))
PowerConsumptionReport.objects.all().aggregate(Min('power '))
PowerConsumptionReport.objects.all().aggregate(Max('power '))
```

Comment: As i need to filter a specific meter and find max value of power for that meter,this technique is not useful,because when i use *filter* , the aggregate method does not work.

Comment: PowerConsumptionReport.objects.filter(meter=1).aggregate(Max('power'))  I think it will work, could you please try it

Comment: @farzanfarahani you are welcome, have a nice coding :)